# how can i make this alarm wake my device up when it is locked

Tags: java, android, alarm, wakelock

i need to let my alarm wake up my device when it is locked
how can i make this alarm wake my device up when it is locked , i try many code but it did not work,

this is my code

```
// Alert Code
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("confirmation");
    alertDialog.setMessage("r u sure u wanna send it");

    // Timer Code
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(CreateNewForm_3.this, 0,
            new Intent(CreateNewForm_3.this, MyAlarmService.class), 0);
    Send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            alertDialog.setButton("yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // -1- InshaAllah we've to send the Case info.
                            // here MMS
                            String FullCaseMsg = "name: " + case1.getName() + "$"
                                    + " gender: " + case1.getGender() + "$"
                                    + " Age: " + case1.getAge() + "$"
                                    + " clothes: " + case1.getClothes()
                                    + "$" + " MoreInfo: "
                                    + case1.getMoreInfo() + "$" + " time: "
                                    + case1.getTime() + "$" + " loc: "
                                    + case1.getLocation() + "$";
                            // -2- then show toast
                            Toast.makeText(CreateNewForm_3.this, "sent ", 0)
                                    .show();
                            // test

                            // -3- starting timer
                            long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                            am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                            am.setRepeating(
                                    AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                                    firstTime + 10 * 1000, 30 * 1000,
                                    pendingIntent);
                            // firstTime Will be the current_time + ( 10 *
                            // 60 * 1000) =)
                            // 10* 1000 will be (10 * 60 * 1000)
                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    bCancel.performClick();
                                }
                            }, (30 * 1000));
                            // ( 30 * 1000) will be firstTime + ( 2-
                            // duration)

                            /*Intent toRecentCases = new Intent(
                                    CreateNewForm_3.this, LMPActivity.class);
                            startActivity(toRecentCases);*/


                            //4-add my case object to list View
                         //All_Static.MyCaseList.add(case1);




                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.setButton2("no",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // here you can add functions

                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            alertDialog.show();
        }

    });

    bCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            am.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
    });
```

any help will appreciate it
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

"AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP" does wake the device when its off,
but I dont think there's a chance to "unlock" (pin or pattern?) the device, as this would be a security issue. (correct me if I'm wrong...).

Comment: i mean code for AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or that is it ? also i do not mean unlock the phone but like an sms just open the lights